# Convert string to an array in blocks of 4

Tags: php, arrays, string

I have the following string:

```
$my_string = 'one|two|three|four|five|six|seven|eight|nine|ten|eleven|twelve|thirteen|fourteen|fifteen';
```

I want to convert `$my_string` to an array with blocks of 4, as follows:

```
$my_array = Array (
array(
    "one",
    "two",
    "three",
    "four"
),
Array (
    "five",
    "six",
    "seven",
    "eight"
),
Array (
    "nine",
    "ten",
    "eleven",
    "twelve"
),
Array (
    "thirteen",
    "fourteen",
    "fifteen"
)
```

How to do this?

I think it can be done with [preg_split()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) function? But I do not know how to do it.

Comment: `explode()` to get an array; And `array_chunck()` for the parts.

Comment: Perfect! How do I give a point to you?

Comment: You can [self-answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) your question if you were able to solve it :)

Comment: Also to your question: 1) "thanks, hi, ..." are considered noise and not needed in a question 2) If you think `preg_split()` is a possible solution, look up the function in the manual, google, THEN try something see how far you can get with it, but if you get stuck and can't get the expected result then come to SO show what you have and where you are stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

one simple line of code...

```
$array = array_chunk(explode('|', $my_string), 4);
```